# Characteristics of commutative rings in a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If R and S are commutative rings with nonzero characteristic and there exists a homomorphism from R onto S, does the characteristic of S divide the characteristic of R? Why?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a good time to recall the definition of "characteristic."

Answer (score 2):

Assume $s$ is the characteristic of $S$ and $r$ is the characteristic of $R$. One has by definition of characteristic that $s1_S=0$ and $r1_R=0$. If $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ we have $\phi(r1_R)=r1_S=0_S$ and this means $r$ is a multiple of $s$
*Edit*: in the case of rings without unity if we assume $\phi$ is onto. Take $y\in S$, $\exists x$ such that $y=\phi(x)$. We have $\phi(rx)=\phi(0)=0=ry$ and this proves $r$ is a multiple of $s$

Comment: How do you know that 1 exists in each ring? (The book I am using defines a commutative ring to be a ring with commutative multiplication.  It does not include 1 as an element of the ring in the definition.)

Comment: @user155242 In this case, for "characteristic" to make sense we need there to be a multiplicative unity. The real question with this is why must $\phi(1_R) = 1_S?$

Comment: Sorry for that. I should have explicited that . To define characteristics we need a unity and homomorphisms between such rings are then defined with $\phi(1)=1$

Comment: @walkar No, we do not need a unit to make sense of characteristic. The characteristic of a ring is the smallest $n$ such that adding any element in the ring to itself $n$ times gives $0$ (if such exists).

Answer (score 0):

Let char $R=n$ and char $S=m$. By Division Algorithm, write $$m=qn+r$$
where $0\leq r\leq n$.
Let $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ be a epimorphism.

Let $y\in S$. Then $y=\phi(x)$ where $x\in R$.
Notice that $my=0$. Thus $\phi(mx)=0$. But $0=\phi(mx)=\phi((qn+r)x)=\phi(rx)=r\phi(x)=ry$.
So we have $ry=0$ for every $y\in S$.
By the minimality of $m$, $r=0$ and $m=qn$, that is $n\mid m$.